# Semistructured document classification

Tags: classification, clustering, text-mining

I am trying to cluster products based on the text descriptions of the products. 
I have millions of products. The nature of the products could be hierarchical. i.e; Clothing will have T-Shirts & Shirts, Jeans etc as child categories. T-Shirts & Shirt will have T-Shirts, Shirt, Collared Tees etc as child categories. The text descriptions will look something like this.

T-shirt 1:

> Blue knitted printed T-shirt, has a Henley neckline, short sleeves with contrast stitched detail along the hems and brand tag on the left hem, short chest button placket, contrast printed detail on the front, a yoke on the back with contrast stitched detail, contrast stitched detail along the hemline

T shirt 2:

> Black knitted T-shirt, has a ribbed round neck, short sleeves, print on the front

Apart from these, I have other info such as price, brand, color, cloth material, etc.

Would k-means give meaningful results? I am not sure if these data can be represented via a geometrical distance.

Comment: What's your task exactly? I'm not able to understand it from your description...

Comment: Create hierarchical clusters of products using the text description available for each of the products. (So not exactly same as similar products)

Comment: All clustering methods basically require that the similarity between objects can be represented by a distance. If you really don't believe that distances can be meaningful here, it is hard to see what can be done. Are you just asking for a distance measure that would work with text descriptions?

Comment: I am not sure if/how tf-idf can be used to measure distance between documents.  
Yes, For now i am looking for method to measure distance between text descriptions and how other inputs such as price, brand etc that are not part of text can be used in the algorithm. 
I am unsure how and what values of k can be given, if i have to use k-means.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get the ball rolling, I'll start with a possible (but probably not optimal) answer.  You could use a bag of words representation with stop-words (frequently used non-informative words such as "the") removed and compute L1 distance between documents.  Probably even better would be to use binary vectors that simply indicate whether a word is included and use hamming distance.

You could other vectors to incorporates your additional information.  For instance, suppose you additionally have price and weight.  For two items define $w_1, w_2$ to be there respective bag-of-words vectors, and $v_1, v_2$ to be vectors containing (price, weight).  You could define the distance between (w1, v1) and (w2,v2) as

$$
d_{Hamming}(w1, w2) + \alpha \cdot d_{L^1}(v1, v2)
$$

$\alpha$ gives you a way of controlling the relative strength of description-paragraph features versus non-description-paragraph features.  I'm sure there are better ways to go about this and that people in this community will know them, but this is a start.